# numpy array - load from disk row by row - memory efficiency but fast

Tags: python, numpy, memory, generator, latency

Is there a way to pipeline numpy array from disk, that are saved this way

```
np.save('data.npy',np.zeros(shape=[500,300,3])) # RGB image
```

and are read row by row (or column by column) in a similar way like generators work, but without the loading latency?

---

**Detailed description**

My application needs near to zero latency, but loading bigger arrays from disk can take some time (~0.02-0.1s). Even this small latency generates unpleasant results.

I have solution for this that satisfies the speed:

```
dictionary = {'array1': array1, ....}
```

with this I can immediately access the arrays, but since I am using raspberry pi Zero, my python program is limited with CPU and RAM, so if I have a lot of arrays, I would be dealing with

```
MemoryError
```

My application reads the array row by row with frequency 50hz, like this

```
for row in array:
    [operation with row]
    time.sleep(0.02) # in reality, whole cycle is 0.02s ( including operation time)
```

I am looking for kind of generator:

```
def generate_rows(path):
    array = np.load(path)
    for row in array:
        yield row
```

This solves the problem with memory, but I **guess** I will lose the near zero latency (loading the array).

Therefore my question is: **Is there a way to generate rows like with generator, but the first rows are ready so to say 'immediately', with near zero latency?**

---

***EDIT: Based on @Lukas Koestler and @hpaulj comments I tried memmap, but the result is suprisingly not good, because memmap crashes on Memory sooner than simply loading full arrays.***

**WINDOWS 10**

I saved 1000 numpy arrays (shape = [500,30,3]) on the disk and tried to cached them with np.load and np.load with memmap read

```
import numpy as np
import os

mats = os.listdir('matrixes')
cache = []
for i in range(10):
    for n in mats:
        cache.append(np.load('matrixes\\{}'.format(n),mmap_mode='r')) # Load with memmap
        #cache.append(np.load('matrixes\\{}'.format(n))) #load without memmap

    print('{} objects stored in cache '.format((i+1)*1000))
```

After running both variants(with memmap and without it), these two errors occured

Memmap after storing 4000 memmaps objects:

```
...
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\memmap.py", line 264, in __new__
    mm = mmap.mmap(fid.fileno(), bytes, access=acc, offset=start)
WindowsError: [Error 8] Not enough memory resources are available to process this command
```

Simple np.load without memmap after caching 5000 np.arrays

```
....
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\format.py", line 661, in read_array
    array = numpy.fromfile(fp, dtype=dtype, count=count)
MemoryError
```

**Raspberry pi Zero**

*As was pointed out by @Alex Yu, I was testing on windows 10, switching to raspberry pi Zero,*

I got above 1000 numpy arrays (took quite long) and then I got

```
1000 objects stored in cache
Killed
```

With Memmaps, i got quite quickly above 1000 memmaps, but I got different errors

```
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py", line 416, in load
    return format.open_memmap(file, mode=mmap_mode)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/lib/format.py", line 792, in open_memmap
    mode=mode, offset=offset)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/memmap.py", line 264, in __new__
    mm = mmap.mmap(fid.fileno(), bytes, access=acc, offset=start)
mmap.error: [Errno 24] Too many open files
```

If I am not wrong, this error happens when opening a lot of files, but not closing them.

Comment: Maybe you could try [numpy.memmap](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.memmap.html) similar to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54444880/recording-data-in-a-long-running-python-simulation).

Comment: `np.load` has a memory mapped mode

Comment: If you have the liberty of choosing the file format I recommend hdf5

Comment: Which version of Windows you use? It could be significant

Comment: @AlexYu considering OP mentioned a Raspberry Pi Zero, I'm guessing the Windows version isn't important.

Comment: @AlexanderReynolds and I see: `File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\format.py", line 661, `

Comment: @AlexYu I am testing this on my notebook. Windows 10.

Comment: It becames even more stranger. Memory-mapping works quite different in Windows and Linux. Results from one OS could be not directly transferrable to another. I suggest you switch to Linux on your development environment

Comment: Or maybe you are using Windows 10 IOT Core on Raspberry?

Comment: @AlexYu I updated my edit. Raspberry pi throws different error

Comment: Aha. We see `mmap.error: [Errno 24] Too many open files`. You can increase them with .. [this link](https://easyengine.io/tutorials/linux/increase-open-files-limit) is good enough. It could work but it raises another suspicions: a) how did you achieve this limit - it could be something wrong here, b) data in your files does not have dependencies between rows, right? you don't need to `groupby` them?

Comment: `"File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py"` - and I suggest that you substitute tags `generator`/`latency` with `python-2.7`

Comment: I have a bit of trouble understanding the question. It seems like you want to read a array-file row-by-row in a fast and memory efficient way. However it also seems like you want to operate on 1000+ of these files (simultaneously?). It could be clearer if you elaborated on how the thousands of files fit into the context of the question of reading *one* file row-by-row.

Comment: @MSeifert On my raspberry pi arrives message to run particular LED strip animation. This animation is in form of RGB image(each row contains values for all chips in the strip).  I need to find the corresponding animation as fast as possible and start feeding the LED strip. Of course new messages can arrive, so I need to feed the strip with several  rows from several sources at the same time

Comment: @MSeifert I only want to clarify, that now everything works fine. But I am kind of at the RAM and CPU limit. I because of this quite limited by the number of animations that can be in 'cache'

Comment: @AlexYu my data is simply matrixes with RGB shape. uint8

Comment: I have suspicion (as @MSeifert notes) that maybe you don't need to work with thousands of open files simultaneuosly? Maybe you don't need thousand files at all? E.g. make a queue in `redis` and make a subscriber for it? If you transfer your question to [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com) - I'm ready to participate

Comment: @AlexYu I will check your proposition, but first I will provide answer based on your advice

Comment: Have you tried to eliminate "mmap.error: [Errno 24] Too many open files"?

Comment: @AlexYu yes. I increased the limit up to 8000objects but I got error  mmap.error: [Errno 12] Cannot allocate memory. Which I think is already fine

Comment: What is cummulative size of your files? E.g. `du -s *`

Comment: @AlexYu 320kb - arrays with shape - [500,30,3]. Just like in question. But in reality its not up to me really. It can be much bigger. I cant right now do your command, because my Pi is finished :D.

Comment: @AlexYu thanks Alex, I will check  the redis queue. But meanwhile I putted answer together

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Thanks to @Lukas Koestler and @hpaulj for directing me into using
>   memmap
>
> and Thanks to **@Alex Yu** for making the solution reality

---

**Solution to my own question**

Using

```
np.load(path,mmap_mode='r')
```

works, but is limited by the limit of opened files. On windows and Linux throws different error:

***WIN***

```
WindowsError: [Error 8] Not enough memory resources are available to process this command
```

***LIN***

```
mmap.error: [Errno 24] Too many open files
```

This was solved with the link given by @Alex Yu [extend limit of opened files](https://easyengine.io/tutorials/linux/increase-open-files-limit).

***Extract:***

*open*

> ```
> /etc/security/limits.conf
> ```

*Paste following towards end:*

> ```
> *         hard    nofile      500000
> *         soft    nofile      500000
> root      hard    nofile      500000
> root      soft    nofile      500000
> ```

***End of Extract***

There is still limitation, but it increased the amount up to 8000 objects in list

```
...
8000 objects stored in cache
```

until

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
mm = mmap.mmap(fid.fileno(), bytes, access=acc, offset=start)
mmap.error: [Errno 12] Cannot allocate memory
```

> **For me this is quite enough**

---

**General Overview of different attitudes toward my problem**

tested on arrays with shape **[500,30,3]**

1) **Simple Load: Without caching**

```
array = np.load(path)
[process rows]
```

> *Slowest but most memory efficient*
>
> cache_limit = 0 (Arrays in dictionary)

2) **Hard cache - loading arrays into dictionary**

```
cache_raw = {i: np.load(i) for i in os.listdir('array_folder')}
...
temporary_array = cache_raw[some_array]
[process rows with temporary_array]
```

> *Ultra fast but very memory inefficient*
>
> cache_limit ~ 1000, (RPI zero) (Arrays in dictionary)

3) **Memmap Cache**

```
cache_memmap = {i: np.load(i,mmap_mode='r') for i in os.listdir('array_folder')}
...
memmap_array = cache_memmap[some_array]
[process rows with memmap_array]
```

> *reasonable speed, memory effiecient*
>
> cache_limit ~ 8000 (RPI zero) (Arrays in dictionary)

---

**Results**

Timing results of loading **first row** for 20 random accesses  for all attitudes:

```
Memmap
0.00122714042664
0.00237703323364
0.00152182579041
0.000735998153687
0.000724077224731
0.000736951828003
0.000741004943848
0.000698089599609
0.000723123550415
0.000734090805054
0.000775814056396
0.00343084335327
0.000797033309937
0.000717878341675
0.000727891921997
0.000733852386475
0.000690937042236
0.00178194046021
0.000714063644409
0.000691175460815
Hard cache
0.000302076339722
0.000305891036987
0.000910043716431
0.000320911407471
0.000298976898193
0.000309944152832
0.000294923782349
0.000304937362671
0.000298023223877
0.00031590461731
0.000324010848999
0.000273942947388
0.000274181365967
0.000286817550659
0.000277042388916
0.000297784805298
0.000288009643555
0.000318050384521
0.00031304359436
0.000298023223877
Without cache
0.0350978374481
0.0103611946106
0.0172200202942
0.0349309444427
0.0177171230316
0.00722813606262
0.0286860466003
0.0435371398926
0.0261130332947
0.0302798748016
0.0361919403076
0.0286440849304
0.0175659656525
0.035896062851
0.0307757854462
0.0364079475403
0.0258250236511
0.00768494606018
0.025671005249
0.0261180400848
```

**EDIT:
Additional computation:**

*Average time of 100 unique accesses. 5x times for each attitude*

```
Memmap
0.000535547733307 # very good speed
0.000488042831421
0.000483453273773
0.000485241413116
0.00049720287323
Hard cache
0.000133073329926 # 4x faster than memmap
0.000132908821106
0.000131068229675
0.000130603313446
0.000126478672028
Without cache
0.0996991252899 # very slow
0.0946901941299
0.0264434242249 # Interesting to note here, something I suspected
0.0239776492119 # np.load has cache in itself
0.0208633708954 # If you load particular numpy array more times in the program,
#it will load faster. Kind of integrated cache
# From my own experience, it is very unreliable and cannot be counted with.
```

Comment: Great work! I think it could be beneficial for other members of community!